# Search box to work like google search

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a  sql query that should return results for user text (Like free text search)which can be a single character or word or combination of words.
For example if I have column named "subject" and its value is `Very long test`, then I want a  query that can give  result if I put `test` or `t` or `e'in the query below

```
  select Subject from [dbo].[Email] where Contains(Subject,'%usertext%')
```

I tried  handling in code behind and then sending it to the query as parameter.
 am editing this question because of so many down votes. Please if you dont understand the question simply comment so I can try to ask more clearly. That would be helping me.

Comment: It's a bit hard to help if we can't see the code to figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: Imagine going to a car repair shop and asking them what is wrong with my car it is making a noise when it should not. How are they suppose to know without inspecting the car. We need to see your code so we can see what the problem could be to help you.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or any jQuery plugin for this?

Comment: Whenever you ask someone what is wrong with your code, they need to first see your code. [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ Hanlet its simple Sql query

Comment: what type of database is on the back-end. why are you using Transact-SQL "CONTAINS" rather than standard SQL "LIKE" keyword? - please provide your query code

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense to me. Why would searching for `verytest` match `very long test`? The word `verytest` doesn't exist in that string... you want to be able to match arbitrary combinations of words within the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `%` character, since the function `Contains` already implied that.
So :

```
select Subject from [dbo].[Email] where Contains(Subject,'t')
```

The `%` are for `LIKE` function

```
select Subject from [dbo].[Email] where Subject LIKE '%t%'
```

Comment: Thanks scorpio it works partly now. I wanted to make it work like google search at the same time want to avoid sql injection. I will dig in more.Thanks everyone for your time.